# How to make bin files executable in gitbash

Tags: git, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

I'm trying to execute a hyperledger fabric project in win 10 with git bash but I got this msg "Cannot execute binary file"
[image: fabric error]

I checked in the bin folder and actually there was no executable permission for these files
[image]
I tried giving permissions with chmod but that didn't do anything. How do I make those executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Bash still runs on Windows and not the Linux kernel that is shipped as part of WSL. It seems you are trying to run the Linux binary here.

You have to start a WSL Linux distribution and run it from there.
The bash shell you are presented then is running on an actual Linux kernel and allows running Linux binaries.

Comment: But I've downloaded the binaries required for win 10(by running a curl cmd given in fabric docs for platform specific binaries)

Comment: Could you please run the following command to test what type of binaries you have?

`od -c -N 4 ./configtxlator`

If these are linux binaries, it should print out the following in the first line:

`0000000 177   E   L   F`

Comment: Yeah I actually copied the ubuntu bin files mistakenly as I was working in ubuntu before coming to win 10. I downloaded the platform-specific bin files again, but now I'm getting something else can you plz help regarding that ==>https://stackoverflow.com/q/67758185/14480330

Comment: Sorry, but I can't answer your new question, I'm not familiar enough with hyperledger fabric to give you a helpful answer regarding that certificate issue.